# How to find the executable file of an app if 'whereis' is not showing it?

Tags: command-line, executable

This basically to do with cuttlefish(The app from showdown) in this case.

I cant find the location of the executable file for it.

The command `whereis` did not give any results!

I want to add it to my start up applications and thus i need the path!

P.S: the preferences of the app are not showing up and ticking against the start automatically thing when the settings for the 1st time showed up is not working!.

So i need to find out the executable/bin file...

How do i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `apt-file search <package-name>` or `dpkg -S <package-name>`, where `<package-name>` is the package you want to search.

Note that these commands will output many results. To find the required package use `grep`:

`apt-file search package | grep -E "(bin/)?package$"`

OR

`dpkg -S package | grep -E "(bin/)?package$"`

This searches the lines whose last word is `package` and may or may not be preceded by `bin/`, for example it will result both `/usr/bin/package` and `/usr/anydirectory/package`.

Comment: Maybe you could instruct the OP to use grep to filter results?

Comment: can you take a look and help me with which from these is the one?-http://paste.ubuntu.com/1151045/

Comment: and the 1st command just gave me this-`nirmik@xxxxxxxxxx:~$ apt-cache search cuttlefish
cuttlefish - A simple reactive tool
`

Comment: Indeed, `apt-cache search` does not report *where* the executable (or any files) from the package is (or would be) installed.

Comment: @EliahKagan...could you help me with the pastebin output?

Comment: corrected the answer.

Comment: output of the dpkg command -http://paste.ubuntu.com/1151102/   which one?

Comment: found it! phew! thanx! :)

Answer (score 2):

Another quick way to find executable programs is to use `locate`, which will **only** show those programs present on your computer. It relies on a database that is automatically updated by `cron` every day. (Use `sudo updatedb` to refresh it manually if you have just installed some programs and cannot find them when using `locate`.)

If, for example, you wanted to find where the dosbox executable is, simply type:

```
locate dosbox | grep bin
```

Which returns,

```
/usr/bin/dosbox
```

Apart from using `whereis`, this is the quickest way to find executables. It can also be used to find readme documents extremely quickly by substituting `bin` for `README`.

Locate is a very useful program and you can even use regex with it if you want to conduct more complex searches. See `man locate` for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Some other commands which (similar to the `whereis`) can tell you where the executable is (all of them detailed in answers to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28555/how-to-find-applications-path-from-command-line) question) are summarized here:

1. [`type`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-type): `type <name>` (shell builtin)
2. [`command`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-command): `command -v <name>` (shell builtin)
3. [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)